# Are magician tricks a form of black magic and are they permissible?

Tags: halal-haram, sihr

I want to know about the black magic and if some magicians do tricks before a crowd, are these tricks considered black magic?  Are these tricks are permissible in Islam.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

no its absolutely haram 
In Quran, Allah Almighty says:

> “Suleman (Solomon) did not disbelieve, but the devils disbelieved teaching men magic.” (2:102)

From this ayah of Quran, it is clear that magic is one of the teachings of Satan. Those who disbelieve follow the path of Satan and these are the ones who rely on magic as a means to fulfilling their desires and make their wishes come true.

Comment: This answer could use some eelaboration, for example you didn't actually answer the main question: "Are magician tricks a form of black magic and are they permissible?" you just declared magic as one of the teachings of Satan and didn't make clear how/why this applies for something everybody knows is only trickery... (see [answer]).